# SharePoint Custom Master Page not Loading all Assets

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, anonymous-authentication

I have a custom Master Page that I crated with custom CSS and JS. Everything works fine as long as the user is logged in.

However, since it is a publishing site, it needs to be working fine for anonymous users as well. But it is not working correctly for anon users.

It shows a login prompt while it should not since it is a publishing site, and if the user ignores that nothing is loaded from the assets mainly the CSS and JS.

Console shows 404 for the assets:

[image]

While logged in things are working. Also, I ensure that required permissions are available on Site level and on Web App level.

The master page and its assets are located under the path:

```
_catalogs/masterpage/CustomMasterPage
```

Comment: seems like some of the assets might be stored in different library, not accessible to no logged users...check if you don't have something in "Site Assets" library / if its accessible for everyone.